# How do I retrieve Eclipse RCP Product Version from IProduct

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I wish to programatically determine the version of my RCP Product.

I've found the Platform.getProduct() method, which returns an IProduct object. But, this does not have version details.  I can navigate into the getDefiningBundle object, but that only has the version id of the plugin project, not the version number in the .product file.

Any tips most welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure the version is included in the exported product. From previous discussion I recall the easiest seems to have the version defined elsewhere and to use a building tool to both include the version in a java class and to change the .product file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually figured out you can query the p2 product IUs to retrieve the versions of installed products.  I'm doing this in a custom splash handler, and have a lot of null guards in as I'm not entirely sure how much of this API will be available in development environment launch configs.  You might be comfortable removing those!  I think you could probably construct a P2 query for the specific product IU instead of looping through all the products like I did.  Pretty sure it's also possible to obtain the active profile without using ProvisioningUI, but that was good enough for me.

```
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.IProvisioningAgent;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine.IProfile;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine.IProfileRegistry;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.IInstallableUnit;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningSession;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.query.IQuery;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.query.IQueryResult;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.query.QueryUtil;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.ProvisioningUI;

private org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.Version getProductVersion() {
    ProvisioningUI provisioningUI = ProvisioningUI.getDefaultUI();
    if (provisioningUI == null) return null;

    String profileId = provisioningUI.getProfileId();
    ProvisioningSession session = provisioningUI.getSession();
    if (profileId == null || session == null) return null;

    IProvisioningAgent provisioningAgent = session.getProvisioningAgent();
    if (provisioningAgent == null) return null;

    IProfileRegistry registry = (IProfileRegistry) provisioningAgent.getService(IProfileRegistry.SERVICE_NAME);
    if (registry == null) return null;

    IProfile profile = registry.getProfile(profileId);
    if (profile == null) return null;

    IQuery<IInstallableUnit> iuProductQuery = QueryUtil.createIUProductQuery();
    IQueryResult<IInstallableUnit> result = profile.query(iuProductQuery, null);
    if (result == null) return null;

    for (IInstallableUnit productIU : result) {
        if (PRODUCT_ID.equals(productIU.getId())) {
            return productIU.getVersion();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hey @stewart-francis - that's great. Thanks!  Sadly, I've now forgotten the why I wanted to know the Produce Version, Doh!

Answer (score 2):

Hi may be this code will help you to get the version of you product file

```
IProduct product = Platform.getProduct();

Version version = product.getDefiningBundle().getVersion();
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your Answers (and questions) you can format your code as a code fragment by selecting the code and clicking on the `{}` button above the text entry area, or by indenting each line by four spaces.  If you wish to format only part of a line you can highlight and click like above, or place `\`` characters around the text you wish to format.

Answer (score 1):

As [@dystroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263525/dystroy) mentioned, the only product version that is available from the IProduct is the defining/branding bundle's version.  If they match, then you're done.

These days, the product version *is* stored in the RCP application's p2 profile, in the product IU.

```
eclipse -noSplash \
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
-metadataRepository \
file://$(pwd)/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/SDKProfile.profile \
-list | grep ^org.eclipse.sdk.ide
```

returns `org.eclipse.sdk.ide=4.2.2.M20121008-1100`.  But I'm not sure of the p2 wizardry necessary to extract IUs from the currently running instance's p2 profile.